# Finding fundamental groups.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

What are the fundamental groups of

1. $\Bbb R^3 \setminus {\rm (two\ parallel\ lines)}$ and
2. $\Bbb R^3 \setminus {\rm (two\ intersecting\ lines)}$.

How do I compute those groups?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know van Kampen?

Comment: Alternatively, see if you can show that the second space is homotopy equivalent to a sphere minus four points.

Comment: Can you show that $\Bbb R^3\setminus\{\text{the origin}\}$ is homotopy equivalent to a sphere? One way is to take $f:\Bbb R^3\setminus\{\text{the origin}\}\to S^2$ to be projection from the origin onto the sphere and $g:S^2\to\Bbb R^3\setminus\{\text{the origin}\}$ to be inclusion. Can you check that this works?

Comment: How do I find maps from one space such that their compositions is homotopic to identity maps? It's quite difficult to me. Can you please help me in this regard? For applying Van Kampen theorem I have to break the space into two spaces which are open, path-connected with simply connected intersection. If we call the intersecting lines to be $C_1$ and $C_2$ then definitely $(2)$ becomes the $(\Bbb R^3 \setminus C_1) \cup (\Bbb R^3 \setminus C_2)$ which are clearly open,path-connected. Is their intersection simply-connected?

Comment: $(\Bbb R^3\setminus C_1)\cup(\Bbb R^3\setminus C_3)$ equals $\Bbb R^3\setminus(C_1\cap C_2)$, not $\Bbb R^3\setminus(C_1\cup C_2)$. I encourage you to draw pictures.

Comment: In fact something more I can show which is $:$ $\Bbb R^3 \setminus \{(0,0,0) \}$ is a deformation retract of $S^2$, the sphere.

Comment: Then how do I proceed?